# unable to convert int to string in SSIS expression

Tags: sql, ssis

hi i'm using below expression for filename with datetime stamp.

```
(DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE() ) ==2  || (DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime]) ==7 ? 
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -3,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls" :
Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -1,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls"
```

which will give me previous date always what is my need.

but when i append filename to this expression it is giving me following error -

```
"FILENAME"+ 
 (DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE() ) ==2  || (DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime]) ==7 ? 
    Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -3,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls" :
    Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -1,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls"
```

ERROR - 
The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Attempt to set the result type of binary operation "@[User::AnimalName] + (DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime])" failed with error code 0xC0047080.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as it states, you cannot implicitly put an integer and a string value together. The resolution is to cast the entirety of the ternary operator to a type of DT_WSTR. Yes, you did cast each of the options to DT_STR but you still have wrap the whole thing in a cast. It's weird but I've run into the same thing before.

```
"FILENAME"+ 
(DT_WSTR, 20)
(
(DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE() ) ==2  
|| (DT_I4)DATEPART("weekday",@[System::StartTime]) ==7 ? 
    Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -3,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls" 
:
    Replace((DT_STR, 20, 1252)(DATEADD( "D", -1,@[System::StartTime])),":","-") + ".xls"
)
```